# How to enable basic metric diagnostics on an Azure VM?

Tags: java, azure, azure-diagnostics

I'm using the [Azure Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/) for VM creation on my Azure account. I noticed that Diagnostics is turned off by default when I create a VM. How do I enable the Basic Metrics in the Diagnostic section while creating a VM?

I'm using the following code to submit a request to create a VM:

```
VirtualMachine request = new VirtualMachine();  
request.setLocation();  
request.setNetworkProfile();  
...  
...  
computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachineOperations().createOrUpdate(request);
```

I see there is a `request.setDiagnosticProfile()` method, but that takes in a BootDiagnostics object and does not enable basic metric Diagnostics.

Is there a way I can enable basic metric diagnostics through code?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT - Seems like the Insights REST API is not working. I get a 202 response, but the monitoring is not enabled.

Comment: Seems only enabling the monitoring via Azure portal, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-how-to-use-diagnostics/.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any Java SDK APIs for enabling basic metric diagnostics via  reviewing the related source codes & javadocs for Azure Java SDK.

But it seems that you can try to refer to the article ["Enabling Azure Diagnostics in Azure Cloud Services"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/) and create a diagnostics setting with Azure [Insights REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931931.aspx) for Azure VM.

Hope it helps.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.